# How to make categories show posts in randomised orded | wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how can I make my categories display posts in randomised orded instead of new to old in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple function through `pre_get_posts` hook will achieve the desired result

```
function change_order_by( $query ) {

    if ( is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'change_order_by' );
```

copy the function above to your `functions.php` and you are good to go.